# Crear función en un modelo para obtener datos de otras tablas, Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Cómo puedo crear una función en un modelo que obtenga datos de otras 3 tablas pero solo necesito un dato de cada tabla ya que actualmente en mi vista muestro los id de cada uno de una unica tabla.

Modelo

```
 class Factura extends Model
 {
    protected $table = "facturas";
    protected $fillable =[
    'numero','detalles','valor','archivo','idcliente','idestado','idforma'
    ];
   }
```

Vista

```
@foreach($facturas as $factura)
          <tr>
            <td>{{$factura->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$factura->numero}}</td>
            <td>{{$factura->detalles}}</td>
            <td>{{$factura->valor}}</td>
            <td>{{$factura->idcliente}}</td>
            <td>{{$factura->idforma}}</td>
            <td>{{$factura->idestado}}</td>
```

Comment: ¿Dichas tablas están relacionadas con el modelo Factura a través de sus respectivos modelos en Eloquent?

Comment: Las tablas solo se relacionan en la base de datos, en los modelos solo se encuentran los atributos que manejo de cada tabla.

Comment: Entonces edita la pregunta y agrega más información sobre las tablas en mención y lo que intentas hacer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

es muy sencillo crea tus relaciones de uno a muchos y de muchos a uno

y prodras hacer algo así {{ $factura->cliente->nombre }}

te dejo el link de la documentacion de hasmany y de Belongs To

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many